# Freemarker iterating over hashmap keys

Tags: java, freemarker

Freemarker has two collection datatypes, lists and hashmaps
Is there a way to iterate over hashmap keys just as we do with lists?

So if I have a var with data lets say:

```
user : {
  name : "user"
  email : "looser@everything.com"
  homepage : "http://nosuchpage.org"
}
```

I would like to print all the user's properties with their value.
This is invalid, but the goal is clear:

```
<#list user.props() as prop>
  ${prop} = ${user.get(prop)}
</#list>
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**Edit:** Don't use this solution with FreeMarker 2.3.25 and up, especially not `.get(prop)`. See other answers.

You use the built-in [keys](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html) function, e.g. this should work:

```
<#list user?keys as prop>
    ${prop} = ${user.get(prop)}
</#list>
```

Comment: the syntax is different in the latest version, as illustrated in the link I posted in my answer. I realize this is an old question, but it comes up highly ranked on Google.

Comment: just a note - you can use `${user[prop]}` as a shorthand

Comment: This is a performance leak: for every key, it needs to retrieve the value. Iterating over the entrySet() doesn't have that problem.

Comment: should be ${user[prop]}

Comment: With the configuration defaults `user[prop]` works as far as `prop` is a `String` (otherwise you need `user?api.get(prop)` currently), but beware, some frameworks (like Struts, I believe) use a now deprecated setup where method names are mixed with `Map` keys, and so if the value of `props` happens to be a method name in the `user` Java object, you get the method instead of what you meant. That's also why in those legacy setups they always use `user.get(prop)`.

Comment: `user?keys` retuns a mixed `map` adding `map` functions like `hashCode` as one of the keys. Using @rees 's way of `keySet()` or `entrySet()` should be OK. I've wasted several hours on this problem!

Comment: Could really use a reason for why not to use this solution anymore. I'm assuming it's a versioning thing, but needs clarification. Blanket statement doesn't help me

Comment: Just a note - it doesn't retain the order. per Freemarker documentation: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html it only does for certain hash. If you are using java LinkedHashMap worked for me

Answer (score 61):

Since 2.3.25, do it like this:

```
<#list user as propName, propValue>
  ${propName} = ${propValue}
</#list>
```

Note that this also works with non-string keys (unlike `map[key]`, which had to be written as `map?api.get(key)` then).

Before 2.3.25 the standard solution was:

```
<#list user?keys as prop>
  ${prop} = ${user[prop]}
</#list>
```

However, some really old FreeMarker integrations use a strange configuration, where the public `Map` methods (like `getClass`) appear as keys. That happens as they are using a pure `BeansWrapper` (instead of `DefaultObjectWrapper`) whose `simpleMapWrapper` property was left on `false`. You should avoid such a setup, as it mixes the methods with real `Map` entries. But if you run into such unfortunate setup, the way to escape the situation is using the exposed Java methods, such as `user.entrySet()`, `user.get(key)`, etc., and not using the template language constructs like `?keys` or `user[key]`.

Comment: This works perfectly. But, I'm seeing errors in springsource IDE. Any idea how to get it fixed? 
Thanks

Comment: @harshavmb What errors? Does it use an outdated FreeMarker plugin perhaps, which comes with an old FreeMarker version?

Comment: Don't think so. Have downloaded latest one from jboss tools. I'll try on other machine and let you know.

Comment: @harshavmb If you enter something like `${x?nosuchthing}` and you hover over it, the error message shown will tell which FreeMarker version it uses. It should be `2.3.25-incubating`.

Comment: strange, I just tried in Mac and couldn't replicate the issue. Issue seems to be only with my vm. I'll have a look on the jar version. However, it is just an error in the editor, but code was executed correctly.

Comment: The `simpleMapWrapper` hint was the information I was looking for for more than a day now. First it took a while to notice that I get mixed method names and map keys and than I had to find out why this happens. Glad to found your answer!

Answer (score 53):

FYI, it looks like the syntax for retrieving the values has changed according to:

http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html

```
<#assign h = {"name":"mouse", "price":50}>
<#assign keys = h?keys>
<#list keys as key>${key} = ${h[key]}; </#list>
```

Comment: How is this syntax different?

Comment: good answer ;-) note that you may have to do a check for a null when printing your value, <#if h[key]??> ${key} = ${h[key]}; </#if>

Comment: The syntax wasn't changed. Both `[key]` and `.get(key)` exists since ancient times. `.get(key)` isn't any special for FTL, it's just calling that public Java method. But you can only use it if FreeMarker was configured to expose `Map` methods.

Comment: When iterating, I get methods (getClass, hashCode,equals, get, toString, class) ... however, I'm not seeing any of the properties like 'id', which is what I want to get a list of. Any suggestions how to get that list of non-method properties from that hash? I need to know those property names. :|

Answer (score 12):

If using a [BeansWrapper](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/api/freemarker/ext/beans/BeansWrapper.html) with an exposure level of Expose.SAFE or Expose.ALL, then the standard Java approach of iterating the entry set can be employed:

For example, the following will work in Freemarker (since at least version 2.3.19):

```
<#list map.entrySet() as entry>  
  <input type="hidden" name="${entry.key}" value="${entry.value}" />
</#list>
```

In Struts2, for instance, [an extension of the BeanWrapper](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/freemarker/StrutsBeanWrapper.html) is used with the exposure level defaulted to allow this manner of iteration.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Because I got an `InvalidReferenceException` when I tried it, while `map?keys` worked.

Comment: This does only work when using `freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper` as object wrapper. Otherwise `Map`s will automatically be wrapped into a `SimpleHash` object which does not support `#entrySet()`. (see http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/api/freemarker/template/SimpleHash.html)

Comment: You are correct, and I have updated my answer to reflect your comment.  Good looking out!

Comment: The above won't work that well for the hash created inside the FTL specially if you are using Spring Freemarker resolver with BeanWrapper. The hash declared inside Ftl file is not wrapped and will still be just a hash iterable using ?keys.

Comment: Do not use pure `BeansWrapper`, at least not with its defaults, where `simpleMapWrapper` is `false`. It gets very confusing, as it mixes keys with method names. If you need to call `entrySet()`, just keep using a "clean" object wrapper, like the default one, and write `map?api.entrySet()` if you need to access the Java API instead of the keys.

Comment: This is helpful, because in my case, when iterating, I get methods (getClass, hashCode,equals, get, toString, class) ... however, I'm not seeing any of the properties like 'id', which is what I want to get a list of. Any suggestions how to get that list of non-method properties from a hash?

Answer (score 2):

### Iterating Objects

If your map keys is an object and not an string, you can iterate it using Freemarker.

1) Convert the map into a list in the controller:

```
List<Map.Entry<myObjectKey, myObjectValue>> convertedMap  = new ArrayList(originalMap.entrySet());
```

2) Iterate the map in the Freemarker template, accessing to the object in the Key and the Object in the Value:

```
<#list convertedMap as item>
    <#assign myObjectKey = item.getKey()/>
    <#assign myObjectValue = item.getValue()/>
    [...]
</#list>
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, it's worth mentioning there's a decent handling of empty collections in Freemarker since recently.

So the most convenient way to iterate a map is:

```
<#list tags>
<ul class="posts">
    <#items as tagName, tagCount>
        <li>{$tagName} (${tagCount})</li>
    </#items>
</ul>
<#else>
    <p>No tags found.</p>
</#list>
```

No more `<#if ...>` wrappers.

Comment: Best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single quote to access the key that you set in your Java program.

If you set a Map in Java like this

```
Map<String,Object> hash = new HashMap<String,Object>();
hash.put("firstname", "a");
hash.put("lastname", "b");

Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("hash", hash);
```

Then you can access the members of 'hash' in Freemarker like this -

```
${hash['firstname']}
${hash['lastname']}
```

Output :

```
a
b
```

Comment: that shows how to address individual keys, but the question asks how to iterate