# Iterating over map in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Freemarker iterating over hashmap keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497777/freemarker-iterating-over-hashmap-keys)

I have a Hash Map which contain item ids as a key and Item objects as a value. Following is the pseudo code -

```
allItems : {
  12: itemObj1 (id:12, name:myitem1)
  13: itemObj2 (id:13, name:myitem2)
  14: itemObj3 (id:14, name:myitem3)
}
```

On result.ftl I need to iterate over this map and get the values of Item Object. I have tried this approach but could not get values from Item object -

```
<#list item?keys as it>
    ${it} = ${item.get(it)[name]}
</#list>
```

Answer (score 10):

I think you want:

```
<#list allItems?keys as it>
  ${it} = ${allItems[it].name} 
</#list>
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Only works if the key is a String, not if it's a Class

Comment: Since 2.3.25 you can use `<#list allItems as key, item> ${key} = ${item[name]} </#list>`. This works with non-`String` keys too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<#assign seq=["a","b","c"]>
<#list seq as l>
  ${l[1]}
// It will print b
  ${l[0]}
//It will print a
</#list>
```