# Freemarker Hashtable<Integer, String>, iterate by keys

Tags: hashtable, freemarker

I have a number of hashtables with Integers as keys, and i want to be able to iterate over them in my Freemarker templates, however, nothing seems to work.

I tried the example from [Freemarker iterating over hashmap keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497777/freemarker-iterating-over-hash-map-keys):

```
<#list user.props() as prop>
   ${prop} = ${user.get(prop)}
</#list>
```

It probably works with Strings as keys, but it didn't with Integers. I also can't even retrieve the value from my hashtable by the concrete value. What i have is:

```
Hashtalbe ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put(1, "hello");
datamodel.put("devices", ht);
```

(datamodel being the hashmap passed to the template).

In the template i do the following:

```
<#if devices??>
 <#list devices?keys as prop>
  <p>${prop}</p>
  <p>${devices.get(1)}</p>

OR

  <p>${devices.get(key)}</p>

OR

  <p>${devices[key]}</p>

OR

  <p>${devices[1]}</p>
 </#list>
<#else>
 <p> no devices</p>
</#if>
```

But none of that works. Can you help me, please?

PS. I converted the hashtable from  into  to pass it to the template, but that seems like a bit of a workaround.

Best regards, 
Timofey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for those of you who may follow my footsteps.
Apparently, FreeMarker can't work with Hashtables with  as parameters. So I ended up creating the versions of these hashtables inti  and, since i had numbers as keys in my hashtables, i was able to do the following in my template:

```
<#list 1..100 as prop>
    <#if hashtable[prop?string]??>
        <option value='${prop}'<#if prop==selected> selected='selected'</#if>>${hashtable[prop?string]}</option>
    <#else><#break>
    </#if>
</#list>
```

Good Luck and may the force be with you :)

Comment: Indeed the problem is that FreeMarker can only handle hashes with keys of type String.

Comment: There's a better solution for this now (using `?api`); see [this FAQ entry](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys).

Answer (score 2):

This is the old issue that FTL's hash type isn't like Java's `Map`, and it [only supports string keys](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys). But, since 2.3.22 you can use `someMap?api.get(someNonStringKey)` to work that around. It needs some configuring to enable, but nothing that breaks an existing application. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794648/606679) or [this FAQ entry](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys).