# Freemarker: How to iterate through the Map using enums as keys

Tags: java, enums, dictionary, key, freemarker

The following code does not work because Freemarker seems to cast the value of the expression inside [] to String and then to use it as a key, which is not what is actually expected.

Preparing a template model:

```
Map<MyEnum, Object> myMap;
myMap.put(MyEnum.FOO, "Foo");
myMap.put(MyEnum.BAR, "Bar");
templateModel.put("myMap", myMap);
```

my.ftl:

```
<#list myMap?keys as key>
    <#assign value = myMap[key]>
    <li>${key} = ${value}</li>
</#list>
```

In the [Freemarker documentation](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#jdk_15_enums) it is described how to access the Enum itself, but I didn't find anything about how to get a value from a hash using Enum as a key.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To paraphrase [Freemarker Documentation FAQ](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/freemarker/app_faq.html#faq_question_14) on this,

> You can't use non-string keys in the myMap[key] expression.  You can use methods!

So, you could create a bean that provides a way for you to get to your Java EnumMap, (i.e).  Then just instantiate this bean with your mapp, and put the bean in your Model.

```
class EnumMap
{
    HashMap<MyEnum, String> map = new HashMap<MyEnum, String>();

    public String getValue(MyEnum e)
    {
        return map.get(e);
    }    
    ..constructor, generics, getters, setters left out.
}
```

I'm a little bit confused about what general goal your trying to accomplish.  If you just need to list out the values of the enum (or perhaps a display value for each one).  There is a much easier way to do it.

One way I've seen this problem solved is by putting a display value on the Enum instances.

i.e

```
enum MyEnum 
{   FOO("Foo"), 
    BAR_EXAMPLE("Bar Example"); 
    private String displayValue;

    MyEnum(String displayValue)
    {
        this.displayValue = displayValue;
    }

    public String getDisplay()
    {
        return displayValue;
    }
}
```

This allows you to put the Enum itself into your configuration, and iterate over all instances.

```
SimpleHash globalModel = new SimpleHash();
TemplateHashModel enumModels = BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance().getEnumModels();
TemplateHashModel myEnumModel = (TemplateHashModel) enumModels.get("your.fully.qualified.enum.MyEnum");

globalModel.put("MyEnum", myEnumModel);
freemarkerConfiguration.setAllSharedVariables(globalModel);
```

Then you can iterate over the enum,

```
<#list MyEnum?values as item>
    ${item.display}
</#list>
```

Comment: But when I want to access a map using the enum as key, it doesn't work. It makes sense that mymap[MyEnum.SOMETHING] doesn't work, but I can't use mymap.get(MyEnum.SOMETHING) either!

Comment: Note that this isn't the simplest solution anymore. See my answer.

Comment: @Wouter Lievens: `mymap.get()` only works with a certain `object_wrapper` setting values (pure `BeansWrapper` with `simpleMaps=false`), but using that value is strongly discouraged, plus changing `object_wrapper` radically under an existing application can very easily break it. Anyway, see my answer for a more "portable" solution.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer isn't the simplest solution since 2.3.22. While `myMap[key]` still assumes a string key ([see FAQ entry why](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys)), now one can use `myMap?api.get(key)` as a workaround. It needs some configuring though:

- First of all, `?api` is disallowed by default, so you need to set the `api_builtin_enabled` (`Configuration.setAPIBuiltinEnabled(boolean)`) setting to `true`.
- Then, the `object_wrapper` (`Configuration.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper)`) used needs to support this feature (exposing the API). If you don't set the `object_wrapper` anywhere, then just increasing the `incompatible_improvements` setting (the `Configuration` constructor parameter, or `Configuration.setIncompatibleImprovements(Version)`) to 2.3.22 solves this. If you set the `object_wrapper` (i.e., you overwrite the default), and it's a `DefaultObjectWrapper` instance, then note that `DefaultObjectWrapper` has its own `incompatibleImprovements` property that has to be set to 2.3.22. If you are using pure `BeansWrapper` (not recommended!) then you have to do nothing, as it always supports this feature.