# How to retrive a List objects from HashMap and iterate in free marker template?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a Java Hashmap object which stores a key value pair in form of `org.w3c.dom.Element`: `java.util.ArrayList`. after populating the `HashMap`, I put it in Freemarker context along with List of `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

When I try to get the List object using below code snippet

```
<#list ElementList as key>
<#assign fh =ElemmentListMap>
  ${fh[key]}
</#list>
```

It says `${fh[key]}` is undefined. Please let me how to get the solution for it or feel free to give another solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Starting from 2.3.22, you should just use `?api` to work this around. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794648/606679), or [this FAQ entry](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys) for details.

**The old answer:**

The root of the problem here is that the FreeMarker Template Language doesn't have an equivalent of the `Map` type of Java. Instead it has a type called "hash", which is similar to a `Map`, but it only supports string keys (variable names, originally). So when it sees `fh[key]`, it will assume that `key` has a string value (in this case that will be the result of `key.toString()` due to how POJO-s are wrapped), and hence will not find the item. So the solution would be not using the `[]` operator for non-string keys, but the Java API, `Map.get(Object key)`.

**And the rest is outdated...**

But you will run into yet another obstacle if you try to do that: the default `ObjectWrapper` doesn't expose the methods of `Map`-s since the string keys of the `Map` already populate the same name-space. I hate the default `ObjectWrapper` for various other reasons too, so I always set up FreeMarker like this:

```
BeansWrapper wrapper = new BeansWrapper();
wrapper.setSimpleMapWrapper(true);
cfg.setObjectWrapper(wrapper);
```

With this wrapper you can use `Map`-s both as `myMap[someStringKey]` or as `myMap(whateverKey)`. So in your case it would be `${fh(key)}`. Again, this doesn't work with the default `ObjectWrapper`.

To make things worse, I see you are using W3C DOM here. The above wrapper doesn't wrap `Node`-s automatically in a way so that you could use the FreeMarker XML features. So if you need that, then unless you always wrap DOM node manually, you will have to extend `BeansWrapper` to recognize DOM Node-s. That's simple to do luckily:

```
public class MyObjectWrapper extends freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper {

    public TemplateModel wrap(Object obj) throws TemplateModelException {
        if (obj instanceof org.w3c.dom.Node) {
           return freemarker.ext.dom.NodeModel.wrap((org.w3c.dom.Node) obj);
        } else {
           return super.wrap(obj);
        }
    }

}
```

The last thing to consider if the environment you are using FreeMarker in already has a custom `ObjectWrapper`. In that case, you better try to extend that somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Your **java code** should be:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("red");
list.add("green");
list.add("blue");
map.put("array_list", list);
```

And the **freemarker template** should be:

```
<#list array_list as i>
    ${i}
</#list>
```

**Output**:

```
red
green
blue
```