# FreeMarker Complex Collection

Tags: spring, struts2, freemarker

I've got a HashMap as `Map<Long, List<Map<String, Object>>> typeAndKno`, in the FreeMarker page, I get the content of this map like this:

```
<#list typeAndKno?keys as typeId>
    ${typeAndKno.get(typeId).get(0).get('TYPE_NAME')}
    <#list typeAndKno.get(typeId) as kno>
         ${kno.get('KNOWLEDGE_ID')}
    </#list>
</#list>
```

This code works fine in Struts2, but after moved to Spring MVC, the code fails. I finally changed the code to this:

```
<#list typeAndKno?keys as typeId>
    ${typeAndKno[typeId]?first['TYPE_NAME']}
    <#list typeAndKno[typeId?string] as kno>
         ${kno['KNOWLEDGE_ID']}
    </#list>
</#list>
```

What's the difference between these two pieces of code? Is there a way to make the first piece of code work in Spring MVC?

Comment: I guess it is because of the OGNL.

Comment: @AleksandrM I can't get it, what does OGNL do for it?

Comment: Because in your second example you are using freemarker built-ins.

Comment: @AleksandrM that is to say, OGNL does something convenient for using freemarker. I wonder how to make it as convenient as in struts 2 in spring MVC

Comment: The difference will be in the FreeMarker `object_wrapper` setting. The one under Spring looks better (but don't write `kno['KNOWLEDGE_ID']` and such, `kno.KNOWLEDGE_ID` is more concise). Only, does it actually work? Like if `typeId` is a long, then `typeAndKno[typeId]` shouldn't work.

Comment: @ddekany I change `typeId` from Long to String in Java code. Is there a way to change the `object_wrapper` in Spring? I can't find any reference on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

As of 2.3.22 there's a much easier and non-disruptive solution for this: configure FreeMarker so that `?api` works, and then you can use the Java API of `Map` where the keys aren't `String`-s. See [this FAQ entry](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794648/606679) for more details.

And Strut's FreeMarker setup is something that's strongly discouraged now. Of course, back then, when they did that, that was maybe the most reasonable workaround, but it isn't anymore for a while, and especially not since 2.3.22.

**Old answer (outdated):**

The way you see Java objects from templates depends on the `ObjectWrapper` used, which is a FreeMarker configuration setting. Based on your example, Struts uses a `BeansWrapper` with its default settings, while Spring possibly uses the `DefaultObjectWrapper`. So that causes the differences. I wouldn't recommend using either, because:

- With `BeansWrapper` with its default settings `Map` keys mix with the method names, with method names having priority. Surely you can safely use `myMap.get(key)` to get around that, but `myMap.get('foo')` is just horrible compared to `myMap.foo`, which will only work as far you have no method called `foo`. Also `?keys` will return a mixture of real keys and method names with it... it's a mess.
- With `DefaultObjectWrapper` you can safely write `myMap.foo`, but you won't be able to get entities with non-string keys, because `myMap[key]` only support strings, and you don't have `myMag.get(key)` anymore.

So what I have usually used with FreeMarker was a `bw = new BeansWrapper(); bw.setSimpleMapWrapper(true)`. With this, the methods of `Map`-s are not visible, just like with `DefaultObjectWrapper`, so you can use `myMap.foo` and `myMap[key]` safely. But if rarely you need to get something with a non-string key, you can use `myMap(nonStringKey)` (yes, with `()` instead of `[]`). This last doesn't work with `DefaultObjectWrapper`. (Hopefully FreeMarker 2.4 will solve this mess with non-string keys nonsense, but it's not like it will be out anytime soon...)

So the next question is how to set the object wrapper with Spring. I'm not at home there. As far as I see, you have a `FreeMarkerConfigurer` bean which has a `freemarkerSettings` property, which is a `Properties` object that's eventually is passed to FreeMarker's `Properties`-based configuration API. So there you should be able add an `object_wrapper` property that refers to the class name of the `ObjectWrapper` to use (or it could just be `beans` to use the default `BeansWrapper` instance like maybe Struts does). Problem is, the property-based API is rather limited, and so you can't both create and configure (call `setSimpleMapWrapper`) a `BeansWrapper` there. You could do that in the spring configuration file of course, but I don't see a way to inject that into the `FreeMarkerConfigurer`, unless you create the *whole* `freemarker.template.Configuration` object as a bean, and inject that into the `FreeMarkerConfigurer` with the `configuration` property of it. So maybe the easiest workaround is extending `BeansWrapper` to override the default of `simpleMapWrapper`, and then referring to the class of that extending class via `object_wrapper`. (Just in case somebody reads this later, it's probable that FreeMarker 2.3.21 will extended the properties configuration API so that you can just set `object_wrapper` to `BeansWrapper() { simpleMapWrapper = true }`.)