# Freemarker not finding existing element in hash

Tags: java, freemarker

Having a very odd issue in Freemarker. I have a JSON map `prices` that contains some pairs (String -> Object). The following code should print all pairs in the map:

```
[#list prices?keys as prop]
    ${prop?c} ${prices[prop?c]!"nothing"} 
[/#list]
```

But the result is:

```
1000010786 nothing 1000010704 nothing
```

That is, it finds the keys but when looking for the element linked to the key, it says there is no such element. Anyone has any idea why may this be the case?

Comment: Are you sure the keys are `String`-s, not numbers? Because you are applying `?c` on them, I suppose they are numbers.

Comment: @ddekany as far as I understand, applying ?c turns it into a String?

Comment: Yes, but if prices has non-String keys, it won't find the items with String keys. Of course, then you have the problem that `[]` only supports string keys... but that's another question.

Comment: @ddekany you are right, we assumed they were strings somehow but they are numbers, ouch. Please answer the question so I can give you the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your keys in the `Map` aren't `String`-s but numbers, yet for the `[]` you give a `String` as `?c` converts the number to a string. Removing the `?c` will cause yet another problem as `[]` only supports `String` keys... About that, see my answer here: [FreeMarker Complex Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449159/freemarker-complex-collection/18491634#18491634)