# Iterating over a map of Object: List in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to iterate in a freemarker template over a `HashMap<SeapSubscription, List<PiNotice>>`.
The map doesn't contain any nulls (in keys or values).

The code in Freemarker is:

```
 <#list subscriptionsWithPiNotices?keys as s>
 ${s.title}

    <#list subscriptionsWithPiNotices[s] as piNotice>
    Autoritate contractanta: ${piNotice.contractingAuthorityName}
    .
    .
    </#list>
</#list>
```

If I remove the iteration from the second list (<#list subscriptionsWithPiNotices[s] as piNotice>) it all works (that is iterating over the map keys, but when I add the second part, trying to iterate over the map-s value, i get a Null / missing exception

> ```
>                            FreeMarker template error: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
> ```
>
> ==> subscriptionsWithPiNotices[s]  [in template "seap-subscription-newsletter.ftl" at line 21, column 16]
>
> Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing,
>   either specify a default value with myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use
>   <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These
>   only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole
>   expression, use parenthessis: (myOptionVar.foo)!myDefault,
>   (myOptionVar.foo)??
>
> The failing instruction (FTL stack trace):
>
> ==> #list subscriptionsWithPiNotices[s] a...  [in template "seap-subscription-newsletter.ftl" at line 21, column 9]
>       #list subscriptionsWithPiNotices?keys...  [in template "seap-subscription-newsletter.ftl" at line 18, column 5]

I repeat, I dumped that HashMap, and it only has one key with one ArrayList having one item inside. So there's no reason to report a null, is it ?

Comment: It's the ages old FTL issue that it doesn't have a `Map` type. It has a "hash" type, but that only supports `String` keys (for sub-variables). Then `BeansWrapper` silently `toString()`-s `s` as `[]` requires a string, and then it doesn't find the `Map` entry of course... You will find some SO answers regarding the possible workarounds.

Comment: What is the type of the key?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed to solve the issue, by configuring a

```
BeansWrapper bw = BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance();
bw.setSimpleMapWrapper(true);
cfg.setObjectWrapper(bw);
```

and then using the

map(key) syntax instead of map[key] or map.key. It seems to work with any type of key class.

Comment: The problem with this is that then you are using pure `BeansWrapper` which has its own warts, also that this won't work on setups that use `DefaultObjectWrapper` (recommended). Since 2.3.22 you can use a much better solution, `?api`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28794648/606679) or [this FAQ entry](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys).

Answer (score 0):

So this is the old issue that the `[]` operator [only supports string keys](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys). Since 2.3.22 you can use `someMap?api.get(someNonStringKey)` to work that around. It needs some configuring to enable, but nothing that breaks an existing application. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794648/606679) or [this FAQ entry](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys).