# Freemarker, Maps and Mongo. Getting a value out a nested structure

Tags: java, maps, mongodb, freemarker

I have a Mongo Database and I am making a small web application to display the values from the database. I'm having a little problem with getting a value from a nested structure.

The database structure I have is:

```
{ 

    "_id": ObjectId("4e244ddcb1633b25c38f2155"),
    "id": "2173",
    "type": "P",
    "title": "Test title", 
    "tag": {
      "0": {
      "_id": ObjectId("4e244ddcb1633b25c38f1fc1"),
      "name": "Education",
      "id": "6"
 }
}  
}
```

What I do is, I get the database from the database and put this in a map and this map I put together with several other maps into one map (root) and put that into the .ftl page. 
I can then read the value in .ftl like: ${root.title} which will ofcourse print 'Test title' in the above example.

I now what to get the value of name in tage so that it can print 'Education'

I don't know how to get this. Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value using Freemarker's built-in's for hashes. Similar to below:

```
<#assign tagKeys = root.tag?keys>
<#list tagKeys as tagKey>
    ${root.tag[tagKey].name}
</#list>
```

I have not tested this yet but generally speaking this should work. You might also want to read some previous answers on SO:

[Freemarker iterating over hashmap keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497777/freemarker-iterating-over-hash-map-keys)

Comment: Thanks that does work! Any idea how I could do a contains on that map? For example: 

if Thanks that does work! Any idea how I could do a contains on that map? For example: 

if ${root.tag.name) contains "Education"{
true } else {
false
}

Comment: @Marc - Glad it worked. As far as your second question - Freemarker supports the seq_contains keyword on collections, but it looks like you want an equality check instead. Using the example I gave above - something like <#if ${root.tag[tagKey].name = 'Education'> ... </#if>. What exactly are you trying to do?