# How To Iterate HashMap in FreeMarker?

Tags: java, hashmap, freemarker

I use this class to wrap the maps that i want see in html:

```
public class ChartTimes {
 String text;
 Map<Integer,Integer> groups_time;
//other code

public Map<Integer, Integer> getGroups_time() {
            return groups_time;
        }

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
       }
```

so i send to freemarker a list of my classes "ChartTimes"

```
List<ChartTimes> timechart_list = new ArrayList();

//other code

request.setAttribute("times", timechart_list);
```

this is the html code:

```
   <#list times as time>
                        ${time.text?html}

                         <#list time.groups_time?keys as key>
                        ${key} - ${time.groups_time[key]}
                        </#list>
    </#list>
```

But the output is this monster:

```
 - { getClass - clone - 2 - = 3 - 0 put - 4 - , remove - get - equals - entrySet - 9 -    , class - class java.util.LinkedHashMap hashCode -
 keySet - size - clear - isEmpty - containsKey - values - empty -
 containsValue - toString - putAll - 0 - { getClass - clone - 2 - = 3 -
 0 put - 4 - , remove - get - equals - entrySet - 9 - 0 class - class
 java.util.LinkedHashMap hashCode - keySet - size - clear - isEmpty -
 containsKey - values - empty - containsValue - toString - putAll
```

instead of the maps that i want. i don't undertand why.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1497777/1065197

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: The type of time.groups_time is List<Integer, Integer> so i expect a thing like: 3 - 2 , 2 - 4 etc.

Comment: I've been trying to answer this but while I could list all the keys in a map I could not access the corresponding values unless the original Map keys (in ChartTimes) where a String. I tried every FM trick I know about but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTL doesn't have a `Map` type. It has a so called hash type, which is just something that can have subvariables, and `?keys` lists the subvariable names (which should be strings). What keys you see depends on the `objectWrapper` configuration setting of FreeMarker, and in this case you see the `Map` keys mixed with the method names... because, you could write stuff like `groups_time.get(foo)` etc. and so `get` is a subvariable. Even if you configure FreeMarker so that it doesn't mix in the methods names (that's the default BTW), you will have trouble using the `[]` operator with non-String keys. Anyway, since here you have access to the `Map` API, just use that. `<#list time.groups_time.entrySet() as keyValuePair>...`, etc.