# Freemarker iterating over hashmap keys in a list

Tags: java, freemarker

**Answer is found : ${account[prop]} instead of ${account.get(prop)} works**

Accounts is a list of map with type like

```
//[{"id":"1","location":"warehouse1"},{"id":"2","location":"warehouse2"}]
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> t = m.t();
root.put("accounts", t);
Writer out = null;
try {
    out = context.response.getWriter();
    T.getViewTpl(tplName).process(root, out);
} catch (IOException | TemplateException ex) {
    T.logger.error(T.class.getName(), ex);
} finally {
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        T.logger.error(T.class.getName(), ex);
    }
}
```

it is to be rendered as a table. One account one row, and one property of account one column. Below code doesn't work. How it could be done? Thanks in advance!

```
<table>
    <#list accounts as account>
    <tr>
        <#list account?keys as prop>
        <td>${account.get(prop)}</td>
        </#list>
    </tr>
    </#list>  
</table>
```

Freemarker error is:

```
FreeMarker template error

The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> account.get  [in template "account.tpl" at line 14, column 23]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be better, you forgot to change user to account, probably while copying from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497777/freemarker-iterating-over-hashmap-keys) ;)

```
<table>
<#list accounts as account>
    <tr>
    <#list account?keys as prop>
        <td>${account[prop]}</td>
    </#list>
    </tr>
</#list>  
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 'user' is a typo. It has been corrected. But still not work.  error by freemarker is : The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> account.keys  [in template "account.tpl" at line 13, column 24]

Comment: How do you pass the map to ftl from Java?

Comment: pasting code here is hard to see. can you please see question updated?

Comment: oh, ${account[prop]} instead of ${account.get(prop)} works! Anyway, thank you!

Comment: oh, I missed that one. Updated answer in case any future generations could find it useful :). Glad you made it work.

Comment: As you only list the values, it could just be `<#list account?values as val><td>${val}</td></#list>`. If you need both the key and the value, you can use `<#list account as key, val><td>${key}: ${val}</td></#list>` since 2.3.24.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check null condition before iterating a list or map

<table>
<#if accounts??>
<#list accounts as account>
    <tr>
    <#list account?keys as prop>
        <td>${account[prop]}</td>
    </#list>
    </tr>
</#list>  
</#if>
</table>
```

Comment: No need for `#if`, you can just write `<#list accounts! as account>`. Though in reality you certainly want to skip the whole table, and  then you can use `<#list accounts!><table>...<#items as account>...</#items>...</table></#list>`.