# Freemarker: iterate over nested array

Tags: arrays, hashmap, freemarker

I want to iterate over a nested array I created in Freemarker but can't figure out how to print each value.

The array var

```
<#assign filters = [
    { "p1" : [ "performance" ] },
    { "p2" : [ "nav" ] },
    { "p3" : [ "quarterly" ] },
    { "f1" : [ "50496", "50497", "50501" ]},
    { "f2" : [ "51202", "51196", "51203", "51246", "51207", "51260" ]},
    { "f3" : [ "50504", "50505", "50506" ]},
    { "f4" : [ "50507", "50508", "50509", "50510", "50512" ]}
]>
```

Iterating over the array

```
<#list filters as filter>
    ${filter}'<#sep>,
</#list>
```

I want to create an output that looks like this:

```
$.plugin.function({
    p1: 'performance',
    p2: 'nav',
    p3: 'quarterly',
    fi: '50496' + '|' + '50497' + '|' + '50501',
    f2: etc....
});
```

My error is this:

> For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically 
>   convertible to string (number, date or boolean), 
>   but this has evaluated to an extended_hash

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Freemarker doesn't have a way to convert filter (a hash) into a string. I think that you want the keys function. Where you now have

```
${filter}'<#sep>,
```

You'd instead call

```
<#list filter?keys as prop>
    ...
</#list>
```

and iterate over those keys. In your example there would only be one key per filter and the value

```
filter[prop]
```

would be the array, that you'd also have to iterate over.

See [Freemarker iterating over hashmap keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497777/freemarker-iterating-over-hashmap-keys)

Comment: That's it! It's three nested lists with the last iterating over the key object.  Thanks!  <#list filters as filter><#list filter?keys as prop>${prop}: '<#list filter[prop] as val>${val}<#sep>|</#list>'</#list><#sep>,</#list>

Answer (score 1):

I think you overcomplicate the data structure by using a list of hash-es. Instead, just use a hash:

```
<#assign filters = {
    "p1" : [ "performance" ],
    "p2" : [ "nav" ],
    "p3" : [ "quarterly" ],
    "f1" : [ "50496", "50497", "50501" ],
    "f2" : [ "51202", "51196", "51203", "51246", "51207", "51260" ],
    "f3" : [ "50504", "50505", "50506" ],
    "f4" : [ "50507", "50508", "50509", "50510", "50512" ]
}>

<#list filters?keys as name>
  ${name}: <#list filters[name] as value>'${value}'<#sep> + '|' + </#list><#sep>,
</#list>
```

(Another possibility would be a list of lists, but that's less natural.)

Comment: This is an excellent answer too.  The object I am creating may be needlessly complicated.  Simplifying it means I can remove one of the nested lists.  However I may not have control over the "real" object format once it's complete.

Comment: It's unlikely that they will use a bunch of Map-s, each strictly with one entry in it though.