# Cannot list a hash on key-value pairs in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

What's wrong with the following template?

```
package ${packageName}

public interface ${entityName} {

<#list methods as methodName, map >
public void ${methodName}(${map}) ;
</#list>

}
```

which gives on version 2.3.23:

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "javaclass.ftl" in line 5, column 29:
Encountered ",", but was expecting:
    ">"
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.generateParseException(FMParser.java:5251)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.jj_consume_token(FMParser.java:5122)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.List(FMParser.java:1431)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:2827)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContent(FMParser.java:3081)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OptionalBlock(FMParser.java:3253)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Root(FMParser.java:3432)
    at freemarker.template.Template.<init>(Template.java:208)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.loadTemplate(TemplateCache.java:495)
```

The documentation [gives the following example](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref.directive.items) for a hash structure

> Listing hashes is very similar, but you need to provide two variable
>   names after the as; one for the hash key, and another for the
>   associated value. Assuming products is { "apple": 5, "banana": 10,
>   "kiwi": 15 }:
>
> ```
> <#list products as name, price>
>   <p>${name}: ${price}
> </#list>
>
>   <p>apple: 5
>   <p>banan: 10
>   <p>kiwi: 15
> ```

Note that my example is before submitting content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected since listing key-value was added in 2.3.25.

http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref.directive.list

> ... and to list the key-value pairs of a hash (since 2.3.25):
>
> ```
> <#list hash as key, value>
>   Part repeated for each key-value pair
> </#list>
> ```

So, upgrade if you can or rewrite your list.

See also:

- [Freemarker iterating over hashmap keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497777/freemarker-iterating-over-hashmap-keys)

Comment: Is 2.3.25 still incubating? It's published documentation, but I chose the non-incubating version on maven!? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker

Comment: You can choose the latest version. "While incubation status is not necessarily a reflection of the completeness or stability of the code, it does indicate that the project has yet to be fully endorsed by the ASF." http://freemarker.org/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this was the source of my confusion.