# Iterate on a map in a map

Tags: freemarker

In java I have a HashMap with an hashmap entry called "CategoriesDocuments". I can call it in front in freemarker with this syntax :

```
${CategoriesDocuments}
```

It is composed by a Key/value system. Here the values are categories which are TreeMap entry again. This categories contains in their values a path.

Basically I want to access to these paths.

What I tried was to get the first values like that :

```
<#list CategoriesDocuments?values as v>
 ${v}
</#list>
```

I have an error telling that v must be a number or a string and not a freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.

When I just type  ${CategoriesDocuments} I have :

```
{E010=[F:\Workspace\uploads\E010108_1216.pdf, F:\Workspace\uploads\E010136.pdf, E051=[F:\Workspace\uploads\E051301_0115.pdf], E090=[F:\Workspace\uploads\E090501_0414.pdf],E230=[F:\Workspace\uploads\E230104_1113.pdf]}
```

E010 are for example the categories, and after that we have the path of the files.

How can I do a kind of list on a list to access the files by iteration?

thanks a lot

Comment: This basically comes down to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497777/freemarker-iterating-over-hashmap-keys albeit nested

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as i said previously it didn't work, i had an error

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the `object_wrapper` configuration setting of FreeMarker here. Some applications, most notably Struts, uses a `BeansWrapper` for that (without changing its `simpleMapWrapper` setting to `true`), which does this horrible thing where the Java methods of the `Map` are exposed, and mixed together with the real keys. Like, `CategoriesDocuments.get` will return the `get(Object)` method itself. So, the `?values` of such a map will contain some methods, mixed with the actual keys. If you can't change the `object_wrapper` (using the default, `DefaultObjectWrapper`, is recommend), because some templates aren't compatible with that change, then try to work this around by exploiting that the Java API of `Map` is exposed: `<#list someMap.values() as value>`

Also, FreeMarker actually can't print map-like data structures directly. You are supposed to list them and then print the keys and values yourself, in the format that you actually need. It happens to work in your case as it just calls `toString()`, but I wouldn't rely on the output of `toString()`, which is pretty much only for debugging in Java.